# Benefit of using UseSubmitBehavior in asp.net button

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, submit

What is the benefit of using UseSubmitBehavior in an asp.net button?

Answer (score 12):

It's lighter and less complicated.  *Without* the behavior it's an `onclick` call to postback through JavaScript...but this is actually harder to deal with on the client when you want your own JavaScript.

For example if I'm adding an `onsubmit` handler to the `<form>` this is much easier/more straightforward when the natural `<form>` submit behavior from a `type="submit"` button is happening, it's also easier with any JS library, tying in your functions in the right order (when not set server-side, when it renders) is *much* easier when there is no client-side `onclick` interfering.

You can tie into event bubbling, the `onsubmit`, set `onclick` events yourself to prevent any default behavior, etc...just easier to deal with all around.

There are other facets as well, but making JavaScript manipulation tremendously simpler is a big one, for me atleast.

Comment: Re. " it's an onclick call to postback through JavaScript.."

Wouldn't it be OnClientClick rather than OnClick for JavaScript??

Answer (score 2):

You can also use it as a workaround to the freezing animation issue. If, for example, you pop up a progress dialog with an animated gif in it when the user click a Submit button, the gif will freeze if you use the normal behaviour. If you set UseSubmitBehavior=False, then the gif will not freeze.

There are various other hacky ways of addresses the freezing gif issue but at least this one is simple.